# Why does \pgfmathresult seem to give two different answers?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfmathparse

I am trying to use `\foreach` loops to make some alternating chains of circles that are connected by lines. I have used `\pgfmathparse` to make the small blue circle oscillate on each side of the big orange circle. For some reason `pgfmathresult` works when positioning the small blue circle, but doesn't seem to work for the line connecting the circles.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \foreach \i in {-3,...,3} {
            \pgfmathparse{pow(-1,\i+3)*0.5};
            \draw[fill=blue!30!white] (\i+0.5,\pgfmathresult) circle (0.1cm);
            \draw(\i,0) -- (\i+0.5,\pgfmathresult) -- (\i+1,0);
            \draw[fill=orange!60!white] (\i,0) circle (0.3cm);
        }
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of current method. The solid line should be connecting the orange and blue circles.]

This output should show the solid lines connected to the small and large adjacent circles.

Comment: `\pgfmathresult` is reused to store basically all intermediate results. There is no guarantee that it will stay the same value after another `\draw` command. Try `\pgfmathsetmacro\circley{...}` instead.

Comment: Thanks that is good to know, but even putting another `\pgfmathparse{pow(-1,\i+3)*0.5};` directly before the line `\draw` command still gives the same answer. Regardless I will try your suggestion

Comment: In this case, you should store the result returned by `pgfmathparse` right after it and before the `\draw` command. But `pgfmathsetmacro` is easier to use in this context. The same drawing couls also be done with nodes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

```
    \documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \foreach \i [evaluate=\i as \in using {pow(-1,\i+3)*0.5}]  in {-3,...,3} {
%           \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\in}{pow(-1,\i+3)*0.5};
            \draw(\i,0) -- (\i+0.5,\in) -- (\i+1,0);
            \draw[fill=blue!30!white] (\i+0.5,\in) circle (0.1cm);
%           \draw(\i,0) -- (\i+0.5,\in) -- (\i+1,0);
            \draw[fill=orange!60!white] (\i,0) circle (0.3cm);
        }
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: draw the lines first so that they stay in the background

Answer (score 1):

The same with nodes:

[image: circles and lines]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}


\begin{document}
    
    \tikzset{
        orangenode/.style={draw,circle,inner sep=0pt,minimum width=6mm,fill=orange!60},
        bluenode/.style={draw,circle,inner sep=0pt,minimum width=2mm,fill=blue!30}
        }
        
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \foreach \i in {-3,...,3} {
            \pgfmathsetmacro\j{pow(-1,\i+3)*0.5};
            \node[orangenode] (O-\i) at (\i,0) {};
            \node[bluenode] (B-\i) at (\i+0.5,\j) {};
        }
        \foreach \i in {-3,...,3} {
            \draw (O-\i) -- (B-\i);
            \pgfmathtruncatemacro\j{\i+1};
            \ifnum \j<4 \draw (B-\i) -- (O-\j); \fi
            }
            
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```